# What are the default callbacks for a ruby script?

Tags: ruby

I just recently discovered a default callback for my ruby scripts: [at_exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit) - it's pretty cool.

How would I find other default callbacks like this? I'd imagine I could write some more flexible/powerful ruby code if I knew how to find all the default callbacks that come with Ruby.

Comment: Have a look at a Kernel module which defines the `at_exit` method: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html. If there is anything like this method it has to be defined there.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit** Some corrections added following Jörg W Mittag's comment.

They are more widely known as *hooks* (perhaps from the influence of emacs lisp). Besides `at_exit`, this is the list of Ruby hooks that I believe to be comprehensive:

```
set_trace_func
initialize
method_missing
singleton_method_added
singleton_method_removed
singleton_method_undefined
respond_to_missing?
extended
included
method_added
method_removed
method_undefined
const_missing
inherited
intitialize_copy
intitialize_clone
intitialize_dup
prepend
append_features
extend_features
prepend_features
```

Comment: sawa has it right, I work with these callbacks frequently and there isn't any missing as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think there is also `prepended` akin to `extended` and `included`. Also, there is `append_features`, `extend_features` and `prepend_features`, which are called by `include`, `extend` and `prepend` and do the actual work (and thus can be used to customize how mixins work), similar to how `initialize` gets called by `new`.

Comment: Where they are (v.2.1): Module->[append_features, const_missing, extended, included, method_added,
method_removed, method_undefined, prepend_features, prepended]; Class->[inherited]; Object->
[respond_to_missing?]; BasicObject->[method_missing, singleton_method_added, singleton_method_removed, singleton_method_undefined]; Kernel->[at_exit, set_trace_func].  I don't know where the following methods (which can be used by any class) are documented->[initialize, intitialize_copy, intitialize_clone, intitialize_dup, extend_features].

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby 2.0.0, [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TracePoint.html) class will help you in this regard, very specific way. It would tell you exactly what are the hooks are being called for any specific piece of code :

Example :

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:c_call) do |tp|
  p [tp.lineno, tp.event, tp.defined_class,tp.method_id]
end

trace.enable do
  class Foo # line num 6
    def bar # line num 7
      12
    end
    def self.baz # line num 10
      13
    end
  end
  Foo.new.bar # line num 14
  Foo.baz
end
# >> [6, :c_call, Class, :inherited]
# >> [7, :c_call, Module, :method_added]
# >> [10, :c_call, BasicObject, :singleton_method_added]
# >> [14, :c_call, Class, :new]
# >> [14, :c_call, BasicObject, :initialize]
```